# Creating product view block with custom template in controller action fails

Tags: magento2, module, blocks, controllers

I want to create a `Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View` block in a custom controller action (which will be used for an AJAX call later on). However I am getting the following error when creating the block (and setting the template):

```
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\ValidatorException): Invalid template file: 'Vendor_Module::product.phtml' in module: 'Magento_Catalog' block's name: 'product\view_0'
```

*app/code/Vendor/Module/Controller/Product/View.php*

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Product;

class View extends \Magento\Catalog\Controller\Product
{
    protected $layoutFactory;
    protected $resultFactory;


    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\LayoutFactory $layoutFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RawFactory $resultFactory
    ) {
        $this->layoutFactory = $layoutFactory;
        $this->resultFactory = $resultFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }


    public function execute()
    {
        $block = $this->layoutFactory->create()
                    ->createBlock('Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View')
                    ->setTemplate('Vendor_Module::product.phtml')
                    ->toHtml();

        $result = $this->resultFactory->create();
        $result->setContents($block);

        return $result;
    }
}
```

*app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/product.phtml*

```
<p>Hello World!</p>
```

*app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/frontend/routes.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="foo" frontName="foo">
            <module name="Vendor_Module" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

I can't find the mistake. The definition of the template (`Vendor_Module::product.html`) plus the template's location should be correct. I also tried putting the template directly in `app/code/Vendor/Module/view` - but that did not change anything.

What could be the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple solution: I forgot the `templates` subfolder in my template's path. So instead of

*app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/product.phtml*

it should of course be

*app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend****/templates/****product.phtml*

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the template in this tree directory app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/product/view/product.phtml

Comment: No, that did not work. That wouldn't make any sense anyway, since the template I am setting for the block is `Vendor_Module::product.phtml`, not `Vendor_Module::product/view/product.phtml`.